# Weird unexpected T_STRING error

Tags: php, symfony, syntax-error, fosuserbundle

I have a weird PHP error in a current Symfony2 project:

```
unexpected T_STRING in /blahblah/Foo/BarBundle/Entity/User.php on line 1
```

This is a pretty standard error, usually linked to a mismatched pair of " or '.

But here is the code of the file User.php

```
<?php
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
{
    // classic user entity
```

The line <?php is line #1. There is no quotes, and the weird thing comes from the fact that this error only appear on my staging server: on 2 development machines with local copies of the code, it behaves as expected with no error or warning.
The file is the correct one, the cache was emptied. I thought that it might be an encoding error but it does not seem to be this. I also thought of namespace issues, but the PHP version on the server is correct (5.3.16)

Do you have any idea what this error can stem from, or in which direction I could search ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it even possible to name classes with `\\`?

Comment: check if the file has BOM (byte order mark), if it does, convert file to regular UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: @IvanHušnjak It's not a BOM - we would see `PHP Fatal error:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /blahblah/Foo/BarBundle/Entity/User.php on line 2` then

Comment: `5.3.1` isn't a correct PHP version: this one is really buggy.

Comment: The class with \ means that it is in the global namespace. It's not its actual name (like with \DateTime). I already checked the file encoding and it's OK.

Comment: @RobinCastlin http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: @ClemKeirua Can you upload the problematic file (or even better, a [simplified version that still reproduces the problem](http://sscce.org/)) somewhere?

Comment: @ClemKeirua has this ever worked on your staging server? or do you have another file with similar contents that works?

Comment: My issue is that I can't reproduce it. It works on 2 different environment (2 dev environment with local copies of the code) but not on the staging server. I'll have a look at the PHP version. Other files which start with <?php have never been an issue

Comment: Correction: php version is 5.3.16

Comment: Did you check line endings (`CRLF`) in that file?

Comment: Is it normal that you call "extends \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User" with an antislash before the namespace of the class ?

Comment: Thanks guys ! It seemed to originate from the line endings. With linux style line endings it works much better !

Comment: @Sybio... I had a good reason for that when I did it I guess, but yeah, the antislash is not supposed to be there

Comment: @ClemKeirua Glad it helped, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, it can help others who, like me, won't think about checking it

Answer (score 2):

Most coding conventions that I worked with *strictly require* using `LF` ('Unix style', `'\x0A'`) line endings in the scripts. And whoever managed to submit code with `CRLF` or, god forbid, `CR` had to endure a royal share of pain. )

It may seem not such a big deal, yet it can save you hours of searching for a weird error - such as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an encoding problem of your file. If your project is encoded UTF8 for example, open your file with your text editor and choose the option "Encoding" -> UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue : the file is already encoded in UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: @Sybio did you read comments of the question? It was already mentioned