# getting syntax error using fopen

Tags: php

I have a php program on a GoDaddy linux server that is just trying to fopen, then fwrite to a file.  It is erroring on the fopen statement.

```
<?php
$filename = "calendar3.data";
$filedata = "Hello world";

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
//fwrite($fp, $filedata);
fclose($fp);

echo "file successfully written";

/*
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''w'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/fwrite.php on line 5
*/
?>
```

I have stripped the program down to almost nothing, still getting the error (shown at bottom of code) whenever I execute the program.

Comment: I don't believe this could actually be the cause of your issue, but maybe try replacing `'w'` with `"w"`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well.  Tried creating a $variable containing a 'w'.  Nothing works.

Comment: The only other things I can think of are file encoding or line endings, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251095/weird-unexpected-t-string-error (though, to be honest, I don't think those apply here)

Comment: The problem is that your parser is trying to turn `'w'` into `''w''` for some really strange reason, and `''w''` is invalid syntax. Replacing `'w'` with `"w"` won't work either, as it will parse to `'"w"'`, which is also invalid. Depending on how your parser is working, you may be able to get away with `htmlspecialchars('w')` or just `w`, but this really should be solved by finding out why your parser is adding additional quotation marks.

Comment: I just ran your code (copy and paste) on http://phpfiddle.org/ and it worked just fine (printed *"file successfully written"*) so there is definitely something strange happening with your server or the way you saved that file.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is non-breaking space instead of a normal space somewhere in your code. Which doesn't allow to parse it properly.
[image]